# PyQt4: Using QFileDialog() to save files not QFileDialog().getSaveFileName()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qfiledialog

I am trying to create a program that allows the user to open a pre-existing file and save current files. For opening a file I am using:

```
dlg = QFileDialog(self, "Open", "", "Yaml(*.yaml)")
        filenames = QStringList()

        if dlg.exec_():
            filenames = dlg.selectedFiles()
            FILE_NAME = str(QFileInfo(filenames[0]).baseName())
```

For saving files I am using:

```
_fileName = QFileDialog().getSaveFileName(self, "Save", "./", "Yaml(*.yaml)")
    FILE_NAME = str(QFileInfo(_fileName).baseName())
```

However, graphically I am noticing differences between the open and save methods.

I know I am not using QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(...)
This is because QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(...) outputs a bunch of errors when loading the GUI.

```
Failed enumerating UDisks2 objects: "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected" 
"Not connected to D-Bus server"
```

Is there anyway that I can use QFileDialog to save files? Note that
QFileDialog() by default has an "Open" button, is there anyway to change this to "Save"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

QFileDialog has a method called setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptMode) which allows you to change between Open and Save. http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#setAcceptMode

Usage for open:

```
QFileDialog.setAcceptMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.AcceptOpen)
```

Usage for Save:

```
QFileDialog.setAcceptMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.AcceptSave)
```